# c++ having strange problem

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, vector

I have a function that creates and insert some numbers in a vector.

```
    if(Enemy2.dEnemy==true)
    {
        pt.y=4;
        pt.x=90;
        pt2.y=4;
        pt2.x=125;
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
            Enemy2.vS1Enemy.push_back(pt);
            Enemy2.vS2Enemy.push_back(pt2);
            y-=70;
            pt.y=y;
            pt2.y=y;
        }
        Enemy2.dEnemy=false;
        Enemy3.cEnemy=0;
    }
```

It should insert 6 numbers in two vectors, the only problem is that it *doesn't* - it actually inserts *more*.

I don't think the snippet will run unless `Enemy2.dEnemy == true`, and it won't stay true for ever.

The first time the snippet runs, then `Enemy2.dEnemy` is set to `false` and it shouldn't run again.

I don't set `Enemy2.dEnemy` to `true` anywhere except when the window is created.

If I insert a break point any where in the snippet, the program will work fine - it will insert ONLY 6 numbers in the two vectors.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

---

ok so i did some debugging.
i found that `Enemy2.dEnemy=false;` is being skipped for some reason.
i tried to do this to see if it was.

```
 if(Enemy2.dEnemy)
    {
        pt.y=4;
        pt.x=90;
        pt2.y=4;
        pt2.x=125;
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
            Enemy2.vS1Enemy.push_back(pt);
            Enemy2.vS2Enemy.push_back(pt2);
            y-=70;
            pt.y=y;
            pt2.y=y;
        }
        TCHAR s[244];
        Enemy2.dEnemy=false;
        if(Enemy2.dEnemy)
        {
          MessageBox(hWnd, _T("0"), _T(""), MB_OK);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, _T("1"), _T(""), MB_OK);
        }
        Enemy3.cEnemy=0;
    }
```

well the message box popped saying 1 and my code worked fine. it seems that `Enemy2.dEnemy=false;` doesn't have time to run ;/
blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah!
ok i found where is the real problem which was causing to insert more than 6 numbers.. 
it was where i was asigning `Enemy2.dEnemy=true;`

```
if(Enemy2.e1)
{
Enemy2.now=time(NULL);
Enemy2.tEnemy=Enemy2.now+4;
Enemy2.e1=false;
}
if(Enemy2.tEnemy==time(NULL))
{
check=1;
Enemy2.aEnemy=0;
Enemy2.dEnemy=true;
}
```

the problem seems that the second if runs more than one time, which is weird!

Comment: Please clarify: what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Is it C++ or the C++ code that has problem?

Comment: Are you using multiple threads?

Comment: There isn't enough context here to explain what's going on - whenever that code runs, it will push exactly six points into each of those vectors. Presumably your problem lies outside it somewhere.

Comment: This might be a time to use the tried and true "std::cout" debug methodology :) Print something out everytime a push_back happens. Are there 12 print-outs? If so... weird. If not... well throw in more couts! Just be judicious and make sure your code doesn't start behaving differently because of the extra console output :)

Comment: i did something like wat you said and it seems there is millions of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: get rid of that abominable `if (Enemy2.dEnemy == true)` - it should be:

```
if (Enemy2.dEnemy)
```

(I also prefer to name my booleans as a readable sentence segments like `Enemy2.isABerserker` or `Enemy3.hasHadLeftLegCutOffThreeInchesBelowTheKnee` but that's just personal preference).

Other than that, the only thing I can suggest is a threading problem. There's nothing wrong with that code per se, but there is a window in which two threads could enter the `if` statement and both start pushing values into your vector.

In other words, if thread 1 is doing the pushing when thread 2 encounters the `if` statement, thread 2 will also start pushing values, since thread 1 has yet to set `dEnemy` to `true`. And don't think you can just move the assignment to the top of the `if` block - that will reduce but *not* remove the window.

My advice is to print out the contents of the vectors in the situation where they have more than six entries and that may give a clue as to what's happened (post the output here if you wish).

---

Re your update that the second `if` below is running twice:

```
if(Enemy2.e1)
{
Enemy2.now=time(NULL);
Enemy2.tEnemy=Enemy2.now+4;
Enemy2.e1=false;
}
if(Enemy2.tEnemy==time(NULL))
{
check=1;
Enemy2.aEnemy=0;
Enemy2.dEnemy=true;
}
```

If this code is executed twice in the same second (and that's not beyond the bounds of possibility), the second `if` statement *will* run twice.

That's because `time(NULL)` give you the number of seconds since the epoch so, until that second is over, you may well be executing the contents of that `if` *thousands* of times (or more).

Comment: +1 for recommending against the `if (condition==true)` idiom.  Always makes me want to scream.

Comment: @paxdiablo, Kristopher Johnson: Please can you share more about this idiom?

Comment: @chubsdad, `condition` is a _boolean_. If you compare that to `true`, where do you stop? Reductio ad Absurdum dictates that you _don't_ stop, leading to such wondrous things as `if ((!((x == true) == true) == false) == true) ...` :-) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404838/do-you-prefer-if-var-or-if-var-0/404846#404846

Comment: @Ramiz, you may _think_ your game uses only one thread. Your OS may have other ideas :-) Put some code inside the `if` statement to append a line to a temp file or increment a global integer which is later printed - that's the only way you can be certain.

Comment: i don't know what to do to append a line to a temp file or increment

Answer (score 1):

If this problem disappears when you put in a breakpoint or a diagnostic output message, that's a strong clue that the problem is undefined behavior, which is usually caused by something like dereferencing an uninitialized pointer or careless use of const_cast.

The cause of the problem probably has nothing to do with the code you're looking at. It's caused somewhere else and just happens to show up here. It's like someone being hit by a falling brick: the obvious symptom is a man lying unconscious on the sidewalk, but the real problem has nothing to do with the man or the sidewalk, it's several stories up.

If you want to find the cause of the error, remove your diagnostics until the problem reappears, then start removing *everything else*. Prune away all of the other code. Whenever the error stops, back up until it starts again; if you don't see the cause of the error, start pruning somewhere else. Eventually the bug will have nowhere to hide.