# Sorting but everything is deleted

Tags: java, sorting

So I was trying to sort words alphabetically using linear sort and delete the word if there is already a word like it. I used the following method:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sorting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] array = new String[] { "pepperoni", "ham", "bacon",
                "pineapple", "ham", "sausage", "onion", "bacon" };

        System.out.println("Before sorting: " + Arrays.toString(array));

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int min = i;

            for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++) {

                if (array[min].compareTo(array[j]) > 0) {
                    min = j;
                }

                else if (array[min].equals(array[j]) == true) {
                    array[j] = "";
                }
            }

            String tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[min];
            array[min] = tmp;
        }
        System.out.println("After sorting: " + Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

But everything is deleted. Without the `else if` statement it will be sorted out, but with it everything is deleted.

```
Before sorting: [pepperoni, ham, bacon, pineapple, ham, sausage, onion, bacon]
After sorting: [, , , , , , , ]
```

Can someone point out what's wrong with this code?

Comment: `if(array[min].equals(array[j]) == true)`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404838/do-you-prefer-if-var-or-if-var-0/404846#404846

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the two for should be:

```
for(i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
```

and

```
for(j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)
```

So you are sure that `i` and `j` are always different. In your implementation in fact, you always compare the element with the element itself, and you (wrongly) assume that it's a duplicate.

Moreover you can use:

```
if(array[min] < array[j])
```

and

```
else if(array[min].equals(array[j]))
```

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Otherwise he compares the element also with itself, that's why I suppose it gets removed at some point.

Comment: @TimCastelijns, because if `j=i`, then `array[min].equals(array[j])` will always be true. And thus all the elements will be replaced with a blank string.
@enrico.bacis +1

Comment: Thanks :-) you should really add that kind of information to the answer